# How to resolve the issue while data is not inserted to a PostgresDB from a CSV file with streamsets pipeline

Tags: postgresql, pipeline, streamsets

I have prepared a pipeline task in streamsets with Directory as a source and kept Postgres DB as a target. The pipeline doesn't fail and it is completed successfully. The problem is that the data doesn't get inserted inside the Postgres table that has been created and the endpoint.

The following were done after facing this error:

1. Write permission for the table has been granted.
2. The Postgres target and the stream sets run in a docker container in which the network of the two containers has been linked correctly.
3. [The docker ports are mapped properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6lxN.png)

How to go through this issue?

Comment: Did you look in the PostgreSQL server log files to see if there are errors which StreamSets failed to pass along?

Comment: I am having the same exact problem. The pipeline is validated and upon preview mode is successful. However, there is no output into the postgres database. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?